# Groovy each method/closure

Tags: groovy, closures

What is the difference between using

```
teams.each(){ team->
//iterate through each team
}
```

and

```
teams.each { team->
//iterate through each team
}
```

Please note in the first one there is a bracket after each and before the closure. We were doing some load testing on our application and noticed that when we use the first one, there are some threads waiting on at this call. But in the second case all works smoothly.

I am curious to know what is the difference here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nothing, they are the same thing.  In Groovy, if the last parameter to a function is a Closure, then it can occur outside the braces, so for example:

```
[1,2,3].inject( 0 ) { acc, it -> acc + it }
```

and

```
[1,2,3].inject( 0, { acc, it-> acc + it } )
```

Are the same thing.  The usual way of writing groovy is to miss out the braces in your example, or put the closure outside the braces in the `inject` example above

Comment: @DhanushGopinath They are both the same.  Can you give an example of what you mean by _"block threads"_?  Maybe add it to your question?

Comment: Tim's answer is correct.  If you compile two groovy scripts (one with an one without the parens) with groovyc, you'll generate class files for both.  If you run those through `javap -c` to view the generated bytecode, you'll see that there is no difference between the two (other than the script names and some timestamps).  They go through the exact same code path.  The OP must have had some other difference in their load test runs.

Comment: Ya. That was not the reason. Finally figured out that a call from the closure was causing the bug - http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/GROOVY-5249